# SQL Server BCP hitting invalid characters at same point in file no matter the input

Tags: sql-server

I am exporting data out of Teradata and using BCP to import into Sql Server (SS) to an empty staging table via a Linux script. After I wrote it I ran a small volume through and all was well. Now I am doing the full volume load of 146 million rows. Around 27+ million rows into it I start getting data thrown out due to invalid characters. If I just extract a segment of the file that includes the keys to the bad records and run that smaller file through there are no errors and data loads fine. If I feed the big file in using a sorted input that is ascending and then do the same again with descending sort the load fails at exactly the same point in the file even though the records at that point in the file are not the same. So I have concluded there is nothing wrong with the input file. It seems to be that when we get to a certain record number in the input (repeatable each time) the errors start occurring. I calculated that this point in the file is just about 2gb. Is it possible there is a limit in Sql Server I am hitting or DBMS setting that needs to be tuned upwards? I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

**Update #2 2016-5-17 21:55 EST - the following is the format file for the BCP plus the BCP command I used.

```
/john/bcp # more *fmt
11.0
7
1       SQLCHAR             0       41      "|"   1     lgx_cus_ext_id                                                                           ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       12      "|"   2     dgtl_cpn_id                                                                              ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       7       "|"   3     dgtl_cpn_src_id                                                                          ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       41      "|"   4     shopr_cpn_rnk_finl_pc                                                                    ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       24      "|"   5     rw_udt_ts                                                                                ""
6       SQLCHAR             0       30      "|"   6     rw_udt_prc_id                                                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       1       "\n"   7     cpn_not_sug_flg                                                                          ""

bcp DIGITALCOUPONSIMPLE.DBO.SHOPR_CPN_RNK_STGG  \
 in ${one_split_file} -c -D -S MSSQLTestServer \
 -U 103866 -P KafRaS4e  -f benchmark.fmt \
 -e /root/john/bcp/benchmark_errors.out \
 -h -h "TABLOCK,ORDER(LGX_CUS_EXT_ID ASC, DGTL_CPN_ID ASC, DGTL_CPN_SRC_ID ASC)"
```

Sample errors:

> Row 27183442, Column 1: Invalid character value for cast specification
>   RK 0 46800846218 00016323936 000012 0.1272 2016-05-06
>   18:18:40.570000 BCP-JQUIRK|0 
>   Row 27183623, Column 4: Numeric value out of range @# 46800846225 00016380967 000011 00011 0.3610 2016-05-06
>   18:18:40.570000 BCP-JQUIRK|0 
>   Row 27183804, Column 5: Invalid date format @# 46800846231 00016380968 000011 0.5020 .7362|2016-05-06
>   18:18:40.570000 BCP-JQUIRK 0 
>   Row 27183986, Column 3: Numeric value out of range

Comment: Are there any error messages logged? It might be helpful if you could post the scripts and/or logfiles that are involved in the process. Some sample data may also help.

Comment: Try to specify batch size `ROWS_PER_BATCH =nnn` in -h hint or exclude -h and use -b (batch size). Also consider to use xml format file.

Comment: Please post table definition i.e. create table script and the first few rows from the file. If you can please include the actual rows that it is complaining about

Comment: Another question: what is "-D"? I cannot find any reference for it in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms162802%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As previous commenter said you do need to provide us with error messages you recieve.
In the meantime check the Connection / Query timeouts, I assume your file is taking a long time to load.
Also check that you are not running out of disk space in the Database.

Comment: The following is a sample of the error messages I am receiving:

Comment: #@ Row 27183442, Column 1: Invalid character value for cast specification @#
RK      0
46800846218     00016323936     000012  0.1272  2016-05-06 18:18:40.570000      BCP-JQUIRK|0
#@ Row 27183623, Column 4: Numeric value out of range @#
46800846225     00016380967     000011  00011   0.3610  2016-05-06 18:18:40.570000      BCP-JQUIRK|0
#@ Row 27183804, Column 5: Invalid date format @#
46800846231     00016380968     000011  0.5020  .7362|2016-05-06 18:18:40.570000        BCP-JQUIRK      0
#@ Row 27183986, Column 3: Numeric value out of range @#

Comment: Do you import a file as 1 file row = 1 column in table or do you load it into separate columns? This looks like it will not parse as date or number: ".7362|2016-05-06 18:18:40.570000"

Comment: Its also possible that your export function is corrupting the file

Comment: See "**Update #2 2016-5-17 21:55 EST" with format file and actual BCP command. I am feeding a pipe delimited file in to load multiple columns. I can feed different data in and it fails on same record number so it is not the data itself. It seems related to being about 2gb into the file I am loading.